# Some CGPoints in array are not recognised

Tags: arrays, swift

I created an array of `CGPoint`s for creating static `SKSpriteNode`s. Some of the points in the array are not recognised when I try to access them on contact with dynamic bodies. Please check the relevant code below.

CGPoints array:

```
var positions : [CGPoint] = [  CGPoint(x: 34.6,y: 256.0),
  CGPoint(x: 90.1, y: 256.0),
  CGPoint(x: 135.4, y: 256.0), 
  CGPoint(x: 200.9, y: 256.0),
  CGPoint(x: 246.3, y: 256.0),
  CGPoint(x: 311.7, y: 256.0),
  CGPoint(x: 357.1, y: 256.0),
  CGPoint(x: 402.5, y: 256.0),
  CGPoint(x: 477.9, y: 256.0), 
  CGPoint(x: 543.3, y: 256.0)]
```

Accessing CGPoints on contact:

```
if firstBody.categoryBitMask == dibCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == squareCategory {
    println("REMOVE X POSITION IS \(secondBody.node?.position.x)")
    if secondBody.node?.position.x == 477.9 {
          println("THAT'S THE POSITION")
      }

    let spritePos = secondBody.node?.position
    var newPositions = positions.filter( {m in m.x != spritePos?.x  })
    freePositions.append(spritePos!)
    spriteCount -= 1
    secondBody.node?.removeFromParent()
    println(newPositions.count)
 }
```

Three points aren't recognised. For example, above  `CGPoint(x: 477.9, y: 256.0)` is one of them. Though the log displays the position correctly, the `if` condition and `filter` are not satisfied.

Comment: Is node?.position.x exactly 477.9, maybe it has higher floating point precision?

Comment: try to use something like this: `if abs(secondBody.node?.position.x - 477.9) < 1e-6 { ... }`, that would be a better approach if you work with floating-point numbers; of course it is just an idea, but if you define the precision what you can accept for considering their values as equal ones, you would not make a huge mistake.

Comment: @holex: I tried something similar to your recommendation but didn't work. Basically, the if is just to check for position, the main thing is `var newPositions = positions.filter( {m in m.x != spritePos?.x  })`. I believe using a more appropriate `filter` to exclude the floating point value or removing the point would solve my problem.

Comment: @NSologistic, have your tried the actual code snippet I have written? I would recommend a trial, it worked for me in _playground_ shamelessly.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you're comparing floating point values, which you should not do with direct compare (==). The thing is that floating point values may contain "subtle errors" and you might end up comparing `477.9` and `477.9000000000000000000000000005`.

The solution is to round numbers before comparison or to check if 
`A-B < some_error_thresold`.
Last one would be something like:

```
fabs(A - B) < CGFloat(FLT_EPSILON)
```

where `FLT_EPSILON` is a standard constant.

Comment: I tried `fabs(A - B) < CGFloat(FLT_EPSILON)` but it didn't work.

Comment: please check my reply to @holex comment

Comment: Look, @NSLogistic, you have strange things in your code, you rely on floating point equality comparison in your filter and in your if. So, if you've really tried floating point stuff we all suggest you to try, than it must be something stupid like spritePos has no value or something. Did you debug this with breakpoints? Do execution even enters your topmost if? I'd suggest to just rewrite the whole thing taking into account that you should not == or != floating point values. So, guess all the filter stuff goes away and such.

Comment: thanks, I tried a different approach. I enumerated the array and used the condition `if abs(value.x - secondBody.node?.position.x) < 1`. This worked for me